# R: How can I merge two column in one (for loger column, not merge by column )

Tags: r, function, merge

For example, I have this data frame:

| Id | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 28 |

and I want to make a long column like this:

| Id | new column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
|  | 14 |
|  | 28 |

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
df1 <- data.frame(New_column = c(df[,"Id"], df[,"Age"]))
merge(df$Id, df1, by="row.names", all=TRUE)[,-1]
```

Output:

```
   x New_column
1  1          1
2  2          2
3 NA         14
4 NA         28
```

Answer (score 3):

We may `unlist` data and create the column by padding `NA` based on the `max` `length`

```
lst1 <- list(df1$id, unlist(df1))
out <- data.frame(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
names(out) <- c("id", "new_column")
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Age = Id) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df %>% 
      mutate(Id = NA)
  ) %>% 
  rename(new_column = Age)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Id new_column
  <int>      <int>
1     1          1
2     2          2
3    NA         14
4    NA         28
```